# How to select rows from csv based on column value and write to another csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, read.csv

I have a csv file (called "`infile`") that looks like below. if the  value in the first column is "student" and the value in the second column is "good", I will write the 3rd and 4th columns of that row into a new file called "outfile", and add header for it called "points" `and "`rank".

I know how to do it in Pandas, **but how to do this with the csv module in python?**
I have tried reader (to read lines from the infile), writer, for loop (and if statements), writerow(), but it never works. Thanks for your help.

| role | status | score | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| student | good | 90 | pass |
| staff | NA | NA | NA |
| student | good | 98 | pass |
| student | poor | 50 | fail |

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is what you have outlined:
Read each row and decide whether to write to output file or not

```
import csv


def keep_row(row):
    return row['role'] == 'student' and row['status'] == 'good'
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = []
    INFILE = 'infile.csv'
    OUTFILE = 'outfile.csv'
    
    with open(INFILE, 'r') as f:    
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if keep_row(row):
                data.append({ 'points': row['score'], 'rank': row['result'] })
    
    with open(OUTFILE, 'w', newline='') as f:    
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=data[0].keys())
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

If you wish to reference docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html